# Jinja2 returns "None" string for Google App Engine models

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

Google App Engine models, likeso:

```
from google.appengine.ext.db import Model

class M(Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
```

Then in a Jinja2 template called from a Django view with an in instance of `M` passed in as `m`:

```
The name of this M is {{ m.name }}.
```

When `m` is initialized without `name` being set, the following is printed:

> The name of this M is None.

The preferable and expected output (and the output when using Django templates) would be/is:

> The name of this M is .

Do you know why this is happening, and how to get the preferred & expected output?

Comment: It's noteworthy that setting a default value, ala. `name = db.StringProperty(default="")` resolves this problem. The problem appears to be that `m.name` is NoneType unless there is a default value.

Comment: Your class should subclass `db.Model`, like so: `class M(db.Model):` -- does that change anything?

Comment: @Jason Hall - Thanks for the catch. That doesn't address the issue, unfortunately.

Comment: I think you hit upon the answer yourself. If you don't specify a name for that property, App Engine appears to store it as `None`, not "", so when it's printed, it gets printed as "None". Specify the default as "" and your problem goes away, like you said.

Comment: @Jason Hall: he's importing Model from the db module, rather than the normal practice of importing db itself.  That's not a problem, except perhaps stylistically.

Comment: @Jason Hall - I think you're right. :) You should submit that as an answer. ;)

Comment: @Wooble I realize that, before his edit he wasn't subclassing Model at all. Which wasn't the cause of his problem, but certainly would make it harder to call `put()` :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might also want to consider using Jinja2's "or"...

```
The name of this M is {{ m.name or ''}}.
```

If `bool(m.name) == False`, this will show `The name of this M is .`

---

If `m.name == False` and you want to display it as the string "False", you can use Jinja2's "default" filter:

```
The name of this M is {{ m.name|default('') }}
```

If `m.name is None`, this will show `The name of this M is .`

If `m.name == False`, this will show `The name of this M is False.`

---

If you want to use the default filter and still have anything evaluating to False shown as your defined default value, add an extra param:

```
The name of this M is {{ m.name|default('', true) }}
```

This should have the exact same effect as `{{ m.name or '' }}`.

---

You can find all of this information on [Jinja2's Builtin Filters reference](http://jinja.pocoo.org/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters)

Answer (score 1):

I think you hit upon the answer yourself. If you don't specify a name for that property, App Engine appears to store it as None, not "", so when it's printed, it gets printed as "None". Specify the default as "" and your problem goes away, like you said.

Comment: It's noteworthy that you may be able to remedy this problem by tinkering with `class jinja2.Undefined` too.

Answer (score 1):

What if he doesn't want empty string to be the default value?

I have this issue myself.  I don't want empty string in there.  I want null/None/NoneType.  That's not the same as empty string.

So I put the question to everyone again --- Jinja insists on translating "None".  What gives?

Comment: I think you can solve this by overloading `jinja2.Undefined` < http://jinja.pocoo.org/api/#undefined-types > and passing that as the `undefined` parameter to your `jinja2.Environment`.

Comment: try to use Jinja filter "default"