# jinja2 on GAE writes out 'None' on every response

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates, jinja2

I get a `None` string at the end of every response no matter how simple is the output from the handler.

Here is my handler code:

```py
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    def render_response(self, _template, **context):
        rv = self.jinja2.render_template(_template, **context)
        self.response.write(rv)


class SimpleHandler(BaseHandler):
     def get(self):
        template_values = {
            'error' : "",
            'url' : os.path.basename(self.request.url)
        }

        self.render_response('temp.html', **template_values)
```

Template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title> 
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
        <div>
            Test
        </div>
        <div>{{ error }}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And finally the output

```
Test
None
```

After this, every output contains the string "None" at the end. Help is appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you include the full code with imports etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note is that `None` will be returned for an empty value (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695180/jinja2-returns-none-string-for-google-app-engine-models)). In order to handle it, you can do something such as this to ensure that an `error` will be printed only if one exists:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
        <div>
            Test
        </div>
        <!-- Here we check to see 'error' is not null; if not, print -->
        {% if error %}
            <div>{{ error }}</div>
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Question for you, why I'm getting also on every response a 'None' string included at the end?
e.g:

class SimpleHandler2(BaseHandler):
     self.response.write('are you there?')

output:
are you there?None

Comment: @user1791567 Can you include the full code you are using when you get that response? Sounds like something else is interacting with / writing to your `response` object.