# In jinja2, how can I configure it (hack it) so None outputs an empty string

Tags: jinja2

I want to jinja to output an empty string if the value is `None` but with no further changes to the template. I see no reason why it should output "None" to an end user, I think it's just bad design.
There are many solutions to make it work by changing the template [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146619/jinja2-outputs-none-string), but I don't want to change the templates.

Is there any way to do this / hack jinja to make it work?

Comment: Have a look at this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695180/jinja2-returns-none-string-for-google-app-engine-models

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suppress "None" output as string in Jinja2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146619/suppress-none-output-as-string-in-jinja2)